# Getting client ip address in Global.asax.cs - is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ip, global-asax

Of course that `Request.UserHostAddress` way is great, however in `Application_Start()` the `Request` object isn't exists yet.

I want to first guess the location of user by his/her IP - just one time -  as he/she enters the web site, and set the default locale for him/her. Then I'll manipulate it some where else.

I think that there must be an event to be overridden in `Global.asax` which `Request` exists in it, However I can't find that event...

Indeed any alternate trick will be appreciated...

**Update**:

In fact, I'm developing a multilingual web site and I use `MaxMind GeoIP` to get the country of users by their IP. So, I want to find a way in order that when a user enters the site (only and only the first request) I retrieve his/her country and store it in Session or a global variable.

I know that I can achieve my goal any where else by `Request.UserHostAddress` and I have not any problem with it - just one line overhead for each request isn't an issue at all for this small app.

However I wonder if it is possible to set that global variable, only and only once...!?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Application_Start()** is not right event, in which you can do this. It will not run for every request from your user, it does some basic initialization of asp.net application.

Better solution is to user, for example

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(){}
```

which runs on beginning of request from client.

About earliest event, in which both request and session will be available... Seems like it is

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
    {
        if (Session["locale"] != null)
        {                  
             //already set variable. 
        }
        else
        {
            //set some variable
            Session["locale"] = "code";
        }
    }
}
```

But what exactly do you want to you mean by "setting locale based on IP"? Can you clarify this task? 'Cause in general, for each request execution this "locale" information must be set.

Comment: I want an event to be fired just one time for every user visiting the site and so, set the default locale just one time for the user. Is that event what I need...?!

Comment: No! That event fires every time that the user sends a request...!

Comment: Yes, there is no event, which will fire only once per user visit. You should check, if user already visited your site, by using, for example, session. But Session is not available in Application_BeginRequest yet.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this like this

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest += (Application_BeginRequest);
}

private void Application_BeginRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = ((HttpApplication) source).Context;
    var ipAddress = context.Request.UserHostAddress;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be solved by using GlobalFilterCollection. You can override the method OnActionExecuting and add the necessary logic. This article: [ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Action Filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters) may help.